Django audio file not playing
Issue with Django and HTML5  Tag: Unable to Play Uploaded Audio Files
Repo: https://github.com/desboisGIT/TestSite
I'm encountering an issue with playing audio files uploaded through my Django application using HTML5's  tag. Here's the setup:
Problem Description:
I have a Django model (AudioFile) with a FileField (audio_file) to upload audio files.
In my template, I'm iterating over a queryset (audio) of AudioFile objects to display audio details and provide a playback option using the  tag.
Template Code Snippet:
{% for file in audio %}
<li>
    <h4>{{ file.title }}</h4>
    <div id="name"><a href="{{ file.audio_file }}" target="_blank">{{ file.name }}</a></div>
    <div id="play">
        <audio src="{{ file.audio_file }}" controls="controls">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
    </div>
</li>
{% endfor %}

Expected Behavior:
Clicking the play button for each audio file should initiate playback directly within the browser using HTML5 audio capabilities.
Steps Taken:
Verified MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT settings in settings.py to ensure media files are correctly served.
Checked Django model setup (models.py) to confirm upload_to path for FileField.
Question:
How can I correctly configure Django and the  tag in HTML5 to play uploaded audio files? What adjustments are needed in the template and model definitions to ensure proper playback functionality?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

first: check what you have in HTML in browser. Maybe you created wrong URLs to audio files - maybe you put only filename without http://..... You could display {{ file.audio_file }} directly in HTML as text to see it - or you can use DevTools in browser to see HTML (or use Ctrl+U to see source HTML in browser)

second: check if in Django you have function which send these files because Django doesn't have to send file automatically (like it doesn't have to send images, CSS files, JavaScript files, other files) You can also use DevTools (tab Network) to see if browser has problem to access files on server. (e.g. error 404)

Do not link to external sources that contain the problem code. Add the code here to have a self contained example. See how to create a [mre]. [Edit] your question.

1. When you accept user uploaded media files, you have to serve these yourself since Django will not do that for you.
You would typically do something like this in the root URLconf of your project to serve these user uploaded media files:
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [•••Rest of code•••]

if settings.DEBUG: #[1]
    urlpatterns += [
        static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    ]
2. audio_file is an instance of FileField and when you access this FileField instance, you are given an instance of FieldFile as a proxy for accessing the underlying file. All these are not native to HTML. So HTML can’t understand this code:
<audio src="{{ file.audio_file }}" controls="controls">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

HTML5 audio.src [MDN]
The URL of the audio to embed.

This means that audio.src expects a URL as argument but you are supplying a FieldFile instance. FieldFile has a url attribute that can enable you get the URL of the underlying file so the fix would be:
<audio src="{{ file.audio_file.url }}" controls="controls">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

[1] Notice the settings.DEBUG? "User uploaded media files" is a very sensitive topic so be careful about this and don’t use this in production.

hi, the comment section is too short but i answered ly self for more.

I understand but what you gave is not an answer though it shows more of what you are doing. I am still obligated to tell you that "that is not how [so] works".

ahah :,), so how am i supposed to do? sorry im new
